# Label_fields are not valid error when using Albumentations

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, machine-learning-model, computer-vision, data-augmentation

I'm not sure if you can have duplicates cross-forums, but my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76788751/label-fields-are-not-valid-even-when-assigning-label-fields-in-albumentations) on Stack Overflow was never answered. I'll paste it here just in case.

I'm using albumentations with the following code:

```py
 augmentor = alb.Compose([alb.RandomCrop(width=450, height=450),
                             alb.HorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
                             alb.RandomBrightnessContrast(p=0.2),
                             alb.RandomGamma(p=0.2),
                             alb.RGBShift(p=0.2),
                             alb.VerticalFlip(p=.5)],
                             bbox_params=alb.BboxParams(format='albumentations', label_fields=['person']))

"intermediary image-loading code"

img = pyplot.imread("path")
coords = [1,2,3,4]
try:
    augmented = augmentor(image=img, bboxes=[coords], class_labels=['person'])

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I get the exception: `Your 'label_fields' are not valid - them must have same names as params in dict`

I looked online and found some other people with the same issue but never found a concrete solution. I also looked at the [documentation](https://programtalk.com/vs4/python/albumentations-team/albumentations/albumentations/augmentations/bbox_utils.py/), and I couldn't decipher how `data` was supposed to relate to my issue. Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Also, for some reason, pressing "tab" doesn't work on this website, so the indentation might be off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a bit stupid. `label_fields=['person']` needs to be changed to `label_fields=['class_labels']`

Also the `[1,2,3,4]` aren't normalized as in the format that the `albumentations` format requires. It's purely there as a placeholder for an actual list.